# Why String type-checks with A, but List[Int] does not with List[A]?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I’m reading through the section on local type inference in Scala’s spec (§6.26.4), more specifically the example 6.26.3.

For the example, there are the following functions and a value defined:

```
def cons[A](x: A, xs: List[A]): List[A] = x :: xs
def nil[B]: List[B] = Nil
val xs = cons(1, nil)
```

where `xs` is inferred to be of type `List[Int]`. So far so good.

Then, the example works with the following value:

```
val ys = cons("abc", xs)
```

That is in turn inferred to be of type `List[Any]`, which perfectly makes sense. What does not make much sense to me is the reasoning for it. It says that the second argument is typed with the expected type `List[a]` (why suddenly lowercase letter btw.?), which is said to fail, because `List[Int]` (the type of `xs`) is not a subtype of `List[a]`. So they retry with typing it as `List[undefined]`, which succeeds. But, the first argument is typed as `String`, no questions asked, although its expected type is `a` (or `A`?).

Moreover, the second strategy only works by replacing type parameters with `undefined` in the type, not the type itself with `undefined` (or is that implied somehow?).

Now the question, `a` being a type constant, why `String` is (apparently) a subtype of `a`, while `List[Int]` is not a subtype of `List[a]`, even though `List` is covariant?

Comment: Is the the type of `xs` in the `String` example a `List[Int]`?

Comment: @wheaties yes, by inference, as noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowercase `a` as a type constant and taking the type param as undefined (when using the pt fails) both appear at the end of the first paragraph for "case 3: methods".

You can't say `List[Int] <:< List[a]` because `a` might turn out to be `String`, for instance.

Since `Int <:< undefined`, you take the type of `xs` as `List[Int]`. That's good, because you want the least upper bound with the other arg's type.  (Imagine that the other arg was a list of something interesting and `a` turned out to be some `Foo`. Those examples usually involve animals: dogs and cats become pets, or whatever.)

In that step, you ask what is `a` really, hence, `a?`.  And then, it better be that `String <: a?`.  It simply picks `String` because it is not a parameterized type.

That's just non-expert verbiage, of course.

Comment: So basically there is a slight unmentioned difference between having expected types of the parameters to be the type parameter itself (as in `String <:< a`) and having the expected type to be a parameterized type? It also leads to a question, why not replace the appropriate type parameters in the argument’s pt with `undefined` immediately?

Comment: If you're asking, does it have to check the x with an undefined pt, there might be a case with overloading where it makes a difference, but I don't have a time slice to pursue that idea just now. I'll try later; thanks for motivation to read more.

Comment: Or maybe… maybe the example is incomplete and it does not state that `String <:< a` can’t be, thus it is typed by replacing (occurences) of `a` with `undefined`, so that `String <:< undefined` can be true. And the first example in the section would then have `List[undefined] <:< List[a]` for `nil`, which is ok. Is it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last bit. nil[B] has a param, and is constrained by List[b?] <: List[a], where you're solving for b and a is fixed. For b it infers Nothing.

Comment: In `String <:< a`, `a` is fixed as well then, although it’s actually some unknown type. But besides that, the first bit is good then? As you said, in `List[Int] <:< List[a]`, this can’t be, because `a` might be a String (but it won’t!), the same as in `Int <:< a`, where `a` might be a String or some Foo or whatever, but again, it won’t, because that is not a solution to the constraint system. So what I’m asking is – is the first arg typed in a way equivalent to the second arg? `String` is not a subtype of `a` (because `a` might be `Int` or `Foo`…), thus `String <:< undefined` is cool.

Comment: @themarketka Yes. Here's a different example showing that how the arg is typed matters. Your question here inspired me to answer precisely there. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25898862/1296806