# Type weirdness with Map#getOrElse

Tags: scala

Consider

```
scala> val m = Map('a -> 3, 'b -> 4)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 3, 'b -> 4)

scala> val d: Double = m.getOrElse('c, 0)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyVal
 required: Double
       val d: Double = m.getOrElse('c, 0)
                                  ^

scala> m.getOrElse('c, 0)
res0: Int = 0

scala> m.getOrElse('a, 0)
res1: Int = 3
```

Why is it that Scala thinks that the  `getOrElse` call returns `AnyVal` even tho it obviously returns an `Int`?

Furthermore, even this fails with the same error:

```
scala> val x: Double = m.getOrElse('a, 0): Double
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyVal
 required: Double
       val x: Double = m.getOrElse('a, 0): Double
```

This however works:

```
scala> val x: Double = m.getOrElse('a, 0): Int
x: Double = 3.0
```

This happens on 2.11.x; I have no tried it on 2.10.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm trying to get better at reading `-Ytyper-debug` output.

With the expected type `Double`, the type of `0` is taken as `Double`, `0.0`.  That's because of the widening conversions people hate.

This is before solving for `B1`. `B1` is taken as `AnyVal` because that is the lub of `A`/`Int` and `Double`.

```
|    |-- Double TYPEmode (site: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    \-> Double
|    |-- m.getOrElse(scala.Symbol("c"), 0) : pt=Double BYVALmode-EXPRmode (site: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |-- m.getOrElse BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |-- m EXPRmode-POLYmode-QUALmode (silent: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    \-> m.type (with underlying type scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int])
|    |    |    [adapt] [B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1)B1 adapted to [B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1)B1
|    |    |    \-> (key: Symbol, default: => B1)B1
|    |    |-- scala.Symbol("c") : pt=Symbol BYVALmode-EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |-- scala.Symbol BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |-- scala.Symbol.apply BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    |    \-> (name: String)Symbol
|    |    |    |    [adapt] Symbol.type adapted to (name: String)Symbol
|    |    |    |    \-> (name: String)Symbol
|    |    |    |-- "c" : pt=String BYVALmode-EXPRmode (silent: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    |    \-> String("c")
|    |    |    \-> Symbol
|    |    |-- 0 : pt=Double EXPRmode-POLYmode (site: value d  in $iw) 
|    |    |    \-> Double(0.0)
|    |    solving for (B1: ?B1) 
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyVal
 required: Double
       val d: Double = m.getOrElse('c, 0)
                                  ^
|    |    \-> <error>
```

Also, `-xprint:typer` shows

```
m.getOrElse[AnyVal](scala.Symbol.apply("c"), 0.0);
```

The [spec explains](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference) (case 3 methods) that the args are typechecked with the expected type of the param, which is why you get the conversion to `Double` there, instead of having the method return an `Int` that is widened to `Double` in the assignment.

Comment: @ErikAllik ha, well, the definition of the green check is what made you happy, not the best answer and not the answer that actually answered the question. Probably the `toDouble` answer tells you what to do so you can finish your work and not get fired. Or lets you complete your semester project, whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the last comment... all I was saying is that all 3 comments are useful and answer the question.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it demonstrates 1st hand hard evidence straight from Mr. Compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The signature of `getOrElse` is:

```
def getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: ⇒ B1): B1
```

With your statement

```
val d: Double = m.getOrElse('c, 0)
```

You are telling Scala that `B1` ought to be `Double`. But `Double` is not a super-type of `Int`, the common supertype instead is `AnyVal`. Therefore, you cannot make that assignment...

Try casting the `Int` result to a `Double` instead:

```
val d /* : Double */ = m.getOrElse('c, 0).toDouble
```

Comment: s/casting/explicitly converting so that B1 is inferred as Int and/

Comment: @som-snytt exactly. In Scala, `toDouble` looks like a method, but technically it's a cast on the JVM.

Comment: Speaking as a non-expert, I call `i2d` a conversion. I call `asInstanceOf` a cast, which can eventually result in a `checkcast` throwing CCE.

Answer (score 6):

Because map is covariant in its second type parameter, we need to use special trick to avoid contravariance problem, i.e. specify an upper bound for this type:

```
def getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1): B1
```

Because you explicitly provide that the return type is `Double`, scalac resolves its common supertype as `AnyVal`, because `Int` and `Double` are subtypes of `AnyVal`. In your second case, scalac sees a type ascription, so it correctly infers `B1` and then casts Int to Double.

Comment: There are 3 cases: in the first example, I don't provide/ascribe any type, and `getOrElse(..., 3)` is `Int` if the 2nd type parameter of the map is also `Int`; what am I missing? In other words, if the call already returns `Int`, why is it necessary to reassure to the compiler that it's an `Int`?

Comment: @ErikAllik in the first example you r writing `val d: Double`, from which scalac tries to infer other types and `B` (`Int` in your case) is covariant, so `getOrElse` needs to escape it, by declaring an upper bound `B1`. So there is a conflict where `B` is Int and `B1` should be a super type of `B`, which is not a double, so scalac goes up for a common super type which is `AnyVal`

Comment: OK, so the type inference is unintuitively taking the `d: Double` to mean that the `getOrElse` returns a `Double`... got it :) The rest just became clear as well.

Comment: I don't understand why B1 can't be exactly B. I remember some people prefer it, for instance the safe version at http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/134gf6eg1z/question-about-option-a-getorelse